# Toggling around in a simple jQuery Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, repeat

Lets say I got this little `span` that I can't modify from its structure or give any surrounding elements. It is like it is. But now I want to display another Text in it and I want them to toggle between each other.

Example: First text stays for 1 seconds -> it gets faded out and the other text will be displayed -> repeat to infinity.

Is it possible to archive this with just the toggle() function? I tried around a bit but nothing really works.

```js
$(function() {

    $('#test').delay(1000).fadeOut(750, function() {
        $(this).text('Some other text!').fadeIn(500);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="test">This Text!</span>
```

Comment: It's possible with `setInterval()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this.

Hope this will help you

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $("#test").fadeOut(750, function() {
    if ($(this).text() == "This Text!") {
      $(this).text("Some other text!").fadeIn(500);
    } else {
      $(this).text("This Text!").fadeIn(500);
    }
  });
}, 1500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="test">This Text!</span>
```